# Centrino Advanced-N 6200 / Dell Studio 1569 Slow Internet

Tags: 14.04, wireless, intel-wireless

I'm hoping someone can help me here, it's a confusing problem. I've been having an issue with my wifi on my computer. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and my laptop is a Dell Studio 1569. What's weird is this problem only started happening about a week ago.

When it first happened I tried restoring to 2 weeks before using Back in Time and that seemed to fix it for a few hours or so but the problem persists. I have seen other people have had problems with the same wireless card as me as well....

This is the result of running "sudo lshw -C network":

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 35
   serial: 00:23:14:61:8b:2c
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-37-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 ip=192.168.0.23 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:43 memory:f0500000-f0501fff
 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 03
   serial: b8:ac:6f:57:af:4f
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:40 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0904000-f0904fff memory:f0900000-f0903fff memory:f0920000-f093ffff
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. :)

EDIT: Wow, surprised I haven't gotten any responses yet. Anyway, my problem has somehow resolved itself (although not from an update as far as I know). I edited the max speed that my router allows and maybe that resolved it, idk. Should I close this question or keep it open just in case?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late... I had a similar problem. My ADN 6200 only connected with 54MBit/s to my router. After searching and trying a while I found out that 11n was disabled in my `iwlwifi.conf`.

You can try it out with

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi -r
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=0
```

Now wait until the WLAN is reconnected and look if your card conntects with a faster bitrate (mine is at 216MBit/s now). If yes look inside `iwlwifi.conf`.

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

You will probably see this line

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

change it to 0.